# looking for java .pdb files, analyze a crash hdmp file

Tags: java, windbg, crash-dumps, jvm-crash

I am trying to analyze .hdmp file (windows crash dump) that contains a java crash.
I am seeing the stack dump crash and all the dlls/modules but not the java ones such as (jvm,nio,etc..).

When I use windbg or Visual Studio it shouts about missing java symbols/.pdb files which do not exist in the jdk/jre. I saw on the internet some answer about getting a **debug** jdk version which i can't find..

Anyone knows how can i get java .pdb files? or to analyze this file in other way without these?

**Here is the analyze -v**

```
windbg -z foo.hdmp
SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
!analyze -v
APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION_AFTER_CALL


Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.8400.0 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [D:\oded\appcrash\WER24CD.tmp.hdmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is:
Windows 7 Version 7600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: Enterprise TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Mon Jun  4 22:42:31.000 2012 (UTC + 3:00)
System Uptime: 76 days 3:25:16.239
Process Uptime: 0 days 8:44:33.000
.............................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(25c8.12b0): Unknown exception - code c0000374 (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa:
00000000`77a5f6fa c3              ret
0:077> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for nio.dll -
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for jvm.dll -
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for java.exe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for net.dll -
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for java.dll -

FAULTING_IP:
ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+62
00000000`77ad6ab2 eb00            jmp     ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x64 (00000000`77ad6ab4)

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000077ad6ab2 (ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x0000000000000062)
   ExceptionCode: c0000374
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000077b4d430

PROCESS_NAME:  java.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000374 - A heap has been corrupted.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000374 - A heap has been corrupted.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000077b4d430

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  java.exe

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000077ad7176 to 0000000077ad6ab2

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffffffffffff

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION_AFTER_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION_AFTER_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION_AFTER_CALL

STACK_TEXT: 
00000000`59fef390 00000000`77ad7176 : 00000000`00000002 00000008`00000023 00000000`00000000 00000007`00000003 : ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x62
00000000`59fef460 00000000`77ad84a2 : 00000000`5578d000 00000000`5578d000 00000007`1e5a91c8 00000000`59fef660 : ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+0x26
00000000`59fef490 00000000`77ad9e34 : 00000000`525d0000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000008`00000003 : ntdll!RtlpHeapHandleError+0x12
00000000`59fef4c0 00000000`77a7c05d : 00000000`66ff4fc0 00000000`525d0000 00000000`66ff4fd0 00000000`5578d000 : ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+0xa4
00000000`59fef4f0 000007fe`ff306db6 : 00000000`0000225c 00000000`66ff4fd0 00000000`66ff4fd0 000007fe`ff30353b : ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x11e74
00000000`59fef570 000007fe`ff306d93 : 00000000`00000007 00000000`8004667e 00000000`0000225c 00000000`00000004 : ws2_32!DSOCKET::`scalar deleting destructor'+0x16
00000000`59fef5a0 000007fe`ff310ad3 : 00000000`0000225c 00000000`526472a0 00000000`59fef718 00000000`00000004 : ws2_32!DSOCKET::DestroyDSocket+0x13
00000000`59fef5d0 000007fe`ff305312 : 00000007`1e5a9200 00000000`59fef760 00000000`5578d1d0 00000000`0000225c : ws2_32!alloca_probe+0x46e0
00000000`59fef660 00000000`6d6c28e3 : 00000002`1907e440 00000000`007083d7 00000001`00000401 00000001`00000000 : ws2_32!ioctlsocket+0x32
00000000`59fef6c0 00000000`029575f3 : 00000007`1e5a91c8 00000002`19081008 00000001`18c2c480 00000000`00000001 : nio!Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_configureBlocking+0x5b
00000000`59fef700 00000007`1e5a91c8 : 00000002`19081008 00000001`18c2c480 00000000`00000001 00000007`1e5a9198 : 0x29575f3
00000000`59fef708 00000002`19081008 : 00000001`18c2c480 00000000`00000001 00000007`1e5a9198 00000000`02def73c : 0x00000007`1e5a91c8
00000000`59fef710 00000001`18c2c480 : 00000000`00000001 00000007`1e5a9198 00000000`02def73c 00000000`000003e8 : 0x00000002`19081008
00000000`59fef718 00000000`00000001 : 00000007`1e5a9198 00000000`02def73c 00000000`000003e8 00000000`02634ed5 : 0x00000001`18c2c480
00000000`59fef720 00000007`1e5a9198 : 00000000`02def73c 00000000`000003e8 00000000`02634ed5 00000002`19498520 : 0x1
00000000`59fef728 00000000`02def73c : 00000000`000003e8 00000000`02634ed5 00000002`19498520 00000000`59fef7a0 : 0x00000007`1e5a9198
00000000`59fef730 00000000`000003e8 : 00000000`02634ed5 00000002`19498520 00000000`59fef7a0 00000001`18c2c480 : 0x2def73c
00000000`59fef738 00000000`02634ed5 : 00000002`19498520 00000000`59fef7a0 00000001`18c2c480 00000002`1907bca8 : 0x3e8
00000000`59fef740 00000002`19498520 : 00000000`59fef7a0 00000001`18c2c480 00000002`1907bca8 00000007`1e5a9218 : 0x2634ed5
00000000`59fef748 00000000`59fef7a0 : 00000001`18c2c480 00000002`1907bca8 00000007`1e5a9218 00000000`02d514e4 : 0x00000002`19498520
00000000`59fef750 00000001`18c2c480 : 00000002`1907bca8 00000007`1e5a9218 00000000`02d514e4 00000002`1907bbd0 : 0x59fef7a0
00000000`59fef758 00000002`1907bca8 : 00000007`1e5a9218 00000000`02d514e4 00000002`1907bbd0 00000002`4320f795 : 0x00000001`18c2c480
00000000`59fef760 00000007`1e5a9218 : 00000000`02d514e4 00000002`1907bbd0 00000002`4320f795 00000000`4320f7ba : 0x00000002`1907bca8
00000000`59fef768 00000000`02d514e4 : 00000002`1907bbd0 00000002`4320f795 00000000`4320f7ba 00000007`1e5a8f90 : 0x00000007`1e5a9218
00000000`59fef770 00000002`1907bbd0 : 00000002`4320f795 00000000`4320f7ba 00000007`1e5a8f90 00000007`00000000 : 0x2d514e4
00000000`59fef778 00000002`4320f795 : 00000000`4320f7ba 00000007`1e5a8f90 00000007`00000000 00000007`1e5a92a8 : 0x00000002`1907bbd0
00000000`59fef780 00000000`4320f7ba : 00000007`1e5a8f90 00000007`00000000 00000007`1e5a92a8 00000000`e3cb5255 : 0x00000002`4320f795
00000000`59fef788 00000007`1e5a8f90 : 00000007`00000000 00000007`1e5a92a8 00000000`e3cb5255 00000007`1e5a9218 : 0x4320f7ba
00000000`59fef790 00000007`00000000 : 00000007`1e5a92a8 00000000`e3cb5255 00000007`1e5a9218 00000000`00000001 : 0x00000007`1e5a8f90
00000000`59fef798 00000007`1e5a92a8 : 00000000`e3cb5255 00000007`1e5a9218 00000000`00000001 00000000`4329305b : 0x00000007`00000000
00000000`59fef7a0 00000000`e3cb5255 : 00000007`1e5a9218 00000000`00000001 00000000`4329305b 00000002`19497a88 : 0x00000007`1e5a92a8
00000000`59fef7a8 00000007`1e5a9218 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`4329305b 00000002`19497a88 00000000`01d189f8 : 0xe3cb5255
00000000`59fef7b0 00000000`00000001 : 00000000`4329305b 00000002`19497a88 00000000`01d189f8 01cd428a`2c12330a : 0x00000007`1e5a9218
00000000`59fef7b8 00000000`4329305b : 00000002`19497a88 00000000`01d189f8 01cd428a`2c12330a 00000000`00000000 : 0x1
00000000`59fef7c0 00000002`19497a88 : 00000000`01d189f8 01cd428a`2c12330a 00000000`00000000 00000002`19497bc0 : 0x4329305b
00000000`59fef7c8 00000000`01d189f8 : 01cd428a`2c12330a 00000000`00000000 00000002`19497bc0 00000007`18038448 : 0x00000002`19497a88
00000000`59fef7d0 01cd428a`2c12330a : 00000000`00000000 00000002`19497bc0 00000007`18038448 4320f726`3f400000 : 0x1d189f8
00000000`59fef7d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000002`19497bc0 00000007`18038448 4320f726`3f400000 00000007`1e5a9170 : 0x01cd428a`2c12330a


FOLLOWUP_IP:
ws2_32!DSOCKET::DestroyDSocket+13
000007fe`ff306d93 4883c428        add     rsp,28h

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  ws2_32!DSOCKET::DestroyDSocket+13

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ws2_32

IMAGE_NAME:  ws2_32.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5be095

STACK_COMMAND:  ~77s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION_AFTER_CALL_c0000374_ws2_32.dll!DSOCKET::DestroyDSocket

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION_AFTER_CALL_ws2_32!DSOCKET::DestroyDSocket+13

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/java_exe/6_0_270_7/4e253d37/ntdll_dll/6_1_7600_16695/4cc7b325/c0000374/000c6ab2.htm?Retriage=1
```

I suspect NIO or Jetty is the cause for this crash and i would like to be able to read the missing stack lines (that are under this line:nio!Java_sun_nio_ch_IOUtil_configureBlocking+0x5b), to know which class/function is calling it, see that:  ERROR: Symbol file could not be found..

Thanks.

Comment: WinDBG can make some use of the exported symbols in the jvm.dll if you add the server directory to the search path. However this might produce missleading results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a debug build of [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/). It has *[pdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)* files for Windows build.
However these builds are not official and may not reproduce the exact error you are getting.

https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds

Comment: these builds don't contain PDB files (openjdk-1.7.0-u80-unofficial-windows-amd64-debug-image for example).

Comment: @RobertBoehne The PDB files are within the diz. These are just zip files. See [here](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds/issues/3#issuecomment-164889177)

Answer (score 0):

You can only contact Oracle support to see if they can help,

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10080305

There seems to be no public symbol files available.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to contact Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IBM SDK to get the java pdb files and set the JAVA_HOME to point to JDK from IBM SDK

Comment: Could you expand upon this answer, such as providing a URL?  A quick Google search did not lead to finding the PDB debug symbols that @oded was looking for.